# submenuitem with contents in menuitem - shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing shiny app where i need to have submenuitem in a menuitem with content in menuitem.

After research from stackoverflow, i found the below link, 
[Show content for menuItem when menuSubItems exist in Shiny Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210709/show-content-for-menuitem-when-menusubitems-exist-in-shiny-dashboard)

But the problem in above solution is whenever i click on submenuitem, the menuitem dropdown gets closed. So i need to click on menuitem again and then click again on menuitem to get the dropdown of submenuitem.

Please help me to solve this issue.

When i click on submenuitem, the dropdown should not automatically close.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

convertMenuItem <- function(mi,tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle']="tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  if(length(mi$attribs$class)>0 && mi$attribs$class=="treeview"){
    mi$attribs$class=NULL
  }
  mi
}

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", 

                dashboardHeader(
                  title = "test"), 
                dashboardSidebar(
                  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                              convertMenuItem(menuItem("Data Scorecard", tabName = "scd",
                                                       menuSubItem("C1", tabName = "comp",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("C2", tabName = "consist",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("C3", tabName = "confirm",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("c4", tabName = "dupli",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("c5", tabName = "inte",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("c6", tabName = "accu",icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                                                       menuSubItem("c7", tabName = "age",icon = icon("angle-double-right"))),"scd"))),


                dashboardBody(
                              tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "scd", 
                                fluidRow(h4("scd"))),

                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "consist",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "confirm",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "dupli",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "inte", 
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "accu",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1"))),
                        tabItem(tabName = "age",
                                fluidRow(h4("c1")))
                )))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please check the image for further clarification.

[image: menuitem dropdown] 
[image: dropdown closes on submenuitem click]

Thanks
SJB

Answer (score 0):

Use `startExpanded = TRUE` argument to menuItem(). It should keep the menu open throughout the session.

```
menuItem("Data Scorecard", tabName = "scd", startExpanded = TRUE, ...)
```