# In Shiny how can I click in a menuItem and show the subItems options on the body?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

This is my {shinydashboard}:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    "User Name",
    subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),

    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",

      menuItem(

        "Dashboard",
        tabName = "dashboard",
        icon = icon("dashboard"),
        menuSubItem(
          "Widgets",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "widgets"
        ),
        menuSubItem(
          "Charts",
          icon = icon("th"),
          tabName = "charts"
        )
      ))),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard",
              tags$button(

                h1('This button takes me to the Widgets Panel')),
              br(),
              br(),
              tags$button(h1('This button takes me to the Charts Panel'))
              ))))


server = function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is to click on 'Dashboard' Menu and then on the body I have a link or button that takes me to the 'Widgets' or 'Charts' Panels.

Once I click on those buttons/links **OR** click on the Sub Menus of 'Dashboard' menu these actions will take me to their Panels.

[image: ShinyDashboard]
So, how can I add the buttons and links that take me to the panels of my Menu SubItems?

And how can I add the buttons and links on the body of my Shiny Dashboard?

Any help would me amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is the result of a common misunderstanding regarding shinydashboard's structure.

Childfull `menuItem`s (like your "Dashboard" `menuItem`) don't have a corresponding `tabItem`.

The only usecase for a childfull `menuItem` is to expand on click and present its children (no visual change in the body - only in the sidebar).

Accordingly in your above code the `tabName = "dashboard"` parameter is ignored and the `tabItem("dashboard", ...)` isn't displayed.

- When a `menuItem` is childfull it accepts the parameters
  `expandedName` and `startExpanded`.
- When a `menuItem` is childless it accepts the parameters `tabName`
  and `selected` (just like `menuSubItem` which always is childless).

Please read [the small print](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html#the-small-print-1).

Also check my related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74313416/how-do-i-include-input-widgets-under-menusubitem-in-shiny-dashboard-sidebar/74314442#74314442) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002467/r-shinydashboard-collapsible-menuitem-with-inputs/71002510#71002510).

However, there are [unofficial workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210709/show-content-for-menuitem-when-menusubitems-exist-in-shiny-dashboard/62834634#62834634) to have a childfull `menuItem` display a `tabItem` - I don't recommend to use them.

To navigate your tabs programmatically use `updateTabItems`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarUserPanel(name = "User Name",
                     subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
                     image = NULL),
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem(
        "Dashboard",
        menuSubItem("Widgets",
                    icon = icon("th"),
                    tabName = "widgets"),
        menuSubItem("Charts",
                    icon = icon("th"),
                    tabName = "charts"),
        icon = icon("dashboard"),
        expandedName = "dashboard",
        startExpanded = TRUE
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("widgets", actionButton("goCharts", "Go to Charts tab")),
      tabItem("charts", actionButton("goWidgets", "Go to Widgets tab"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$goCharts, {
    updateTabItems(session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "charts")
  })
  observeEvent(input$goWidgets, {
    updateTabItems(session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "widgets")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```